# Service message in TeamCity not work

Tags: service, command-line, message, teamcity-9.1

Command line

```
echo ##teamcity[setParameter name='test' value='0.%build.number%']
echo %test%
```

Log

```
[Step 1/1] ##teamcity[setParameter name='test' value='0.10']
[Step 1/1] 0
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All parameter references resolved before executing script, so if `test` has value 0 before writing script into file, script content would be

```
echo ##teamcity[setParameter name='test' value='0.10']
echo 0
```

Proper solution would be store `0.%build.number%` in some variable and use it, e.g.

```
_test="0.%build.number%"
echo "##teamcity[setParameter name='test' value='0.$_test']"
echo $_test
```